# Bug: Google Drive Embed Video unable to play for non authenticated users

Tags: video, google-drive-api

Videos from Google Drive embedded with the Iframe, doesn't work if the user is not authenticated showing this message:

`Unable to play this video at this time. The number of allowed playbacks has been exceeded. Please try again later.`

[Sample Page](https://googledrive.com/host/0B0CnV_gvF2TgeEtRVG5TNVJaZjA/)

Ex of the embed:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0CnV_gvF2TgeEQzbEI0NkhQVHc/preview" 
width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

The videos worked fine yesterday, but today only user logged in with their Google Account inside the browser can play the videos.

Found SO answer about a [limit of download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710781/1562589) but even newly uploaded videos have the same problem.

N.B. All files are shared "Anyone with the Link can view" not public as they should be accessible but not indexed

UPDATE: Videos back online playing without a problem since 2014-09-25 11:50AM (GMT+2)

UPDATE2: ... and broke again as of 16:30 2014-09-25

Comment: This is not limited to just videos. We were using this kind of feature as well and it stopped working a couple of days ago for  non-authenticated users (i.e. those that didn't login to their Google account, any Google account).

Answer (score 0):

its not an acknowledged known problem by google either in the free subscriber forums or in the paid business applications forums.   It appears to be an induced issue from the ongoing google drive upgrade where the standard google container for serving videos hosted on google drive within google sites is now broken... if you use a 3rd party container like JWPlayer the problem goes away.

More details and a workaround here:  https://sites.google.com/site/videohostingdemo/

Comment: The main problem with this workaround is that the videos need to be made public, so they can end up in search results, and it's not a thing we want to happen.

Comment: i see well yes that would be an issue ... however google just fixed the problem so i think your issue went away

Comment: I think it's working sometimes, but most of the time is broken. Now it's down again.

Comment: you might look into the "X-Robots-Tag HTTP header" as a method of preventing your pages from showing in search results